# Efficiently combine two uneven lists into dictionary based on condition

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists of tuples and I want to map elements in `e` to elements in `s` based on a condition. The condition is that the 1st element of something in `e` needs to be >= to the 1st element in `s` and elements 1+2 in `e` need to be <= to elements 1+2 in `s`. The 1st number in each `s` tuple is a start position and the second is the length. I can do it as follows:

```
e = [('e1',3,3),('e2',6,2),('e3',330,3)]
s = [('s1',0,10),('s2',11,24),('s3',35,35),('s4',320,29)]

for i in e:
    d = {i:j for j in s if i[1]>=j[1] and i[1]+i[2]<=j[1]+j[2]}
    print(d)
```

Output (what I want):

```
{('e1', 3, 3): ('s1', 0, 10)}
{('e2', 6, 2): ('s1', 0, 10)}
{('e3', 330, 3): ('s4', 320, 29)}
```

Is there a more efficient way to get to this result, ideally without the for loop (at least not a double loop)? I've have tried some things with `zip` as well as something along the lines of

`list(map(lambda i,j: {i:j} if i[1]>=j[1] and i[1]+i[2]<=j[1]+j[2] else None, e, s))`

but it is not giving me quite what I am looking for.

The elements in `s` will never overlap. For example, you wouldn't have ('s1',0,10) and ('s2', 5,15). In other words, the range (0, 0+10) will never overlap with (5,5+15) or that of any other tuple. Additionally, all the tuples in `e` will be unique.

Comment: In the worst case you can't do any better than a doubly nested loop (suppose every element in `e` is `('ex', 1, 0)` and every element in `s` is `('sx', 0, 2)`). Do you have any additional constraints so that we can do better on average? E.g., is the result set sparse compared to the space of all possible results?

Comment: @FMc That's actually not true in general thankfully. The constraints they specified are associative in some sense and let you avoid a lot of additional comparisons. In the worst-case you might still have 2 loops worth of output, I think we can do better than that for most inputs.

Comment: @HansMusgrave They only constraints are the ones listed. Would that mean what I have is as good as it would get?

Comment: @formicaman Kind of. Right now your solution takes `len(e) * len(s)` time even if `len(results) == 0`. I'm working on an answer that has running time a little higher than `len(results) + len(e) + len(s)`, which for most inputs would be faster. If you don't have additional constraints then there would still be inputs where that idea would be slower, but they shouldn't come up often.

Comment: @HansMusgrave Thanks. Yeah, the only things are that the range from i[1] to i[2] needs to be within s[1] to s[2] --- if it is create that mapping.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "overlap" a bit? From your comments on my answer I get that it means there can only be one s-value for each e-value, but it's not super clear from the question what "overlap" does to imply that.

Comment: Added some more information.

Comment: Ohhh, interesting. Just to clarify, is it considered an overlap if two tuples share an endpoint, e.g. `(0, 5)` and `(5, 10)`?

Comment: That shouldn't ever occur also. It would be (0,5) and then (6,10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint that the tuples in `s` can't overlap is pretty strong. In particular, it implies that each value in `e` can only match with at most one value in `s` (I think the easiest way to show that is to assume two distinct, non-overlapping tuples in `s` match with a single element in `e` and derive a contradiction).

Because of that property, any s-tuple `s1` matching an e-tuple `e1` has the property that among *all* tuples `sx` in `s` with `sx[1]<=e1[1]`, it is the one with the greatest `sum(sx[1:])`, since if it weren't then the s-tuple with a small enough 1st coordinate and greater sum would also be a match (which we already know is impossible).

That observation lends itself to a fairly simple algorithm where we linearly walk through both `e` and `s` (sorted), keeping track of the s-tuple with the biggest sum. If that sum is big enough compared to the e-tuple we're looking at, add the pair to our result set.

```
def pairs(e, s):
  # Might be able to skip or replace with .sort() depending
  # on the rest of your program
  e = sorted(e, key=lambda t: t[1])
  s = sorted(s, key=lambda t: t[1])

  i, max_seen, max_sum, results = 0, None, None, {}
  for ex in e:
    while i < len(s) and (sx:=s[i])[1] <= ex[1]:
      if not max_seen or sum(sx[1:]) > max_sum:
        max_seen, max_sum = sx, sum(sx[1:])
      i += 1
    
    if max_seen and max_sum > sum(ex[1:]):
      results[ex] = s[i]

  return results
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! There will never be duplicate keys -- in other words no two elements in `e` will ever be the same.

Comment: You're welcome :) Perhaps I wasn't clear about the keys; an element in `e` can match a ton of elements in `s`, but Python doesn't allow `{'e1': 's1', 'e1': 's2'}` (or, it over-writes results if you try).

Comment: Yes, but the key should be the tuple ('e1',0,0). The two other element in the tuple should make it unique.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to avoid too lengthy of a comment and made the example too reductive: Consider `e = [('e1', 3, 0)]` and `s = [('s1', 2, 8), ('s2', 1, 9)]`. By the rules you outlined your output pairs consist of `(e[0], s[0]) and (e[0], s[1])`, but that falls apart when you try to shove it into a dictionary; if you write `{e[0]: s[0], e[0]: s[1]}` you'll instead just get `{e[0]: s[1]}`. If you want that clobbering behavior then I think the algorithm I gave above can be refined a bit (or you can wrap `results` in a `dict`), but it _can_ happen unless your data is pretty special.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in the question -- the elements in `s` will never overlap.

Comment: No worries. That's actually a pretty huge constraint, and it means there are solutions that are several times faster and use a ton less memory. If that matters you might consider amending your question or asking a new one. (Briefly, one solution is to replace `RangeIndex` with a structure that only maintains the biggest `sum(t[1:])`. That's simple enough you could cut out the entire class and just keep track of that biggest element too).